# google maps ruler

Tags: google-maps

does someone know how can i add the distance ruler to my api map, or any other quick way to se the distance bwtween 2 direct points?

Answer (score 1):

You could try some of the js extensions available online. For example:
http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/source/browse/trunk/extensions/examples/ruler.html?r=41

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Google Maps API, but given latitude and longitude of any two points you can use a [great circle calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) to determine the distance between them.